# Subversion - tagging only for releases, no branching

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm a small developer committing to a repository on a solo basis, only I would ever administrate and contribute to a project. Given this I have 2 questions -

1. Is it possible to simplify my workflow and and do all active development in **trunk**? Then at a point in time I consider a release (enough bug fixes or a new feature) to create a **tag** with semantic versioning and then proceed to make this a public release?

Tags:

```
   v1.0.0 // Code is being used in production
    v1.1.0 // Add some functionality
    v1.2.0 // Add other new functionality
    v1.2.1 // Fix bug
```

Workflow:

build new features in trunk until stable ->  tag version -> build new features in trunk until stable (repeat)

2. Is this approach wise and are there any disadvantages to it? I would test the code of **trunk** on a QA/testing server first, create a **tag** once the code is satisfactory, then release this tag into a production environment. This tag would then have an accompanying changelog listing the revision number.

**Note:** After reading articles on this website and this for example http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.when.html - I've seen that no branch approach can be taken, given the levels of complexity with branching and merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to simplify my workflow

Yes

> Is this approach wise

No, see below

> and are there any disadvantages to it?

Yes - you will have *some troubles* with bugfixing in released versions (will require branching|merging anyway) and|or detecting known in older codebase errors in trunk's code